How to exclude files at publish in Visual Studio
There is a Visual Studio web project. On its publish I would like to exclude certain files for example the rosyln folder and other DLLs.
The solution should work both for local publish and deployment via Azure DevOps.
I edited the *.csproj file and included this XML, but all the specified files are still getting published.
<ItemGroup>
    <!-- Exclude specific files -->
    <None Remove="bin\System.ValueTuple.dll" />
    <None Remove="bin\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll" />        
    <None Remove="bin\MyProject.Hotfixes.pdb" />
    <None Remove="bin\MyProject.Hotfixes.dll" />
    <None Remove="bin\roslyn**\*" />    
  </ItemGroup>

I also tried replacing None with Publish in the nodes.
This is what I see in the VS console while publishing.


You could also try to  add  an <ExcludeFilesFromDeployment> and/or <ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment> element in the desired  element in your profile.pubxml publishing profile.
For example
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121.
-->
<Project>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <DeleteExistingFiles>false</DeleteExistingFiles>
        <PublishUrl>your publish folder</PublishUrl>
        <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
        <ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>bin\System.ValueTuple.dll;bin\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll;bin\MyProject.Hotfixes.pdb;bin\MyProject.Hotfixes.dll</ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>
        <ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>bin\roslyn\**\*</ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>

Update
Another workaround:
You can use publish.ignore to exclude files/folders from publishing in similar ways as to using a .gitignore.
1.From the Package Manager console execute Install-Package PublishIgnore –pre
2.Edit the publish.ignore file to add files/folders to be excluded
3.Publish
For more information, please read doc:Web Publishing a simpler way to exclude files/folders from being published

Will this work in the Azure DevOps deployment also, or is it just for the local publish. Thank you

I think both work, but I haven't tested it on the DeVops pipeline.

Hi @sukesh, you can also try to use publish.ignore file  to exclude files/folders from publishing in similar ways as to using a .gitignore.

try this:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="CustomCleanAfterPublish" AfterTargets="Publish">
    <!-- Delete specific files after publish -->
    <Delete Files="$(PublishDir)System.ValueTuple.dll;$(PublishDir)Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll;$(PublishDir)MyProject.Hotfixes.pdb;$(PublishDir)MyProject.Hotfixes.dll" />
    <!-- Delete the roslyn directory after publish -->
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(PublishDir)roslyn" />
  </Target>
</Project>



Unfortunately, that did not work. During the publish, I still see the status is console Publishing bin\roslyn and all the excluded files/folders also got published.

really can you show me the output @sukesh

I have added a snap in the question. Please check. Thank you.

@sukesh i have edited the solution i think that will do the work for you

No luck unfortunately!

did you remove the publish directory and re run the publish @sukesh

Yes I did. Also, unloaded, reloaded and rebuilt the project before publishing.
